# modal pop-up closed and not refresh when open again

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having modal pop-up with some validation, when I click on button it opens that modal with two text boxes and when I type there value I've some validation that put some text in case the entry is not valid, now when I close the modal and open it again I see the errors.

I want to refresh the modal after close or in every time that I open it, any idea what is wrong here?

I've tried the following and its not working ...I can see the alert but the modal is not refreshed.

```
function close() {
    alert("test");
    //$("#MYModal").removeData('bs.modal').empty();
    //$(document.body).removeClass('modal-open');
    $("#MYModal").removeData();
}
```

Threre was suggestion to use the  following

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(e.target).removeData('bs.modal').html('');
});
```

But the problem is that after I close the modal its not opend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The removeData method removes data attached to elements.  What you want to do is just find the inputs inside the modal and set the value of the to empty strings.

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('input').val('');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/bDECE/)

Comment: Thanks but Ive try it and nothing happen when I open the modal again the errors and showen with the fields values...,any other idea?

Comment: Sorry, I had the this in quotes... but I also like what @ashumehta suggests.  If you have a form element wrapped around those inputs, you can use the form reset method.

Answer (score 0):

reset form data when popup open

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#form_id')[0].reset();
})
```